# Extract the filename or url of the current source of mediaobject in phonon

Tags: pyqt4, phonon

I'm trying to make a lyrics viewer in my music player created using pyqt and phonon module.for that i need to extract the url of local file or filename of the current source. Is there any idea how i can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[QUrl MediaSource.url(self)](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/phonon-mediasource.html#url) is what you are after.